# Keep order in Kafka after reproducing messages by using Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I use Apache Kafka as my Storm spout.
I receive the messages from Kafka, process these messages and them send them back to the Kafka.

I wonder if I can keep the messages in same sequence. i.e.

topic01: A, B, C -> Storm -> topic02: A_, B_, C_

I used one spout and one bolt to try to keep the order, but it won't work.
I tried OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout too, but the order still changed.

So are there any solutions to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka only guarantees ordering within partitions. You can keep this order per partition within Storm if you use `fieldsGrouping` on partition ID and write the result to the same partitions for the result topic.

Comment: Yes! If I change the number of partition to be 1, I can keep the order. And How should I get the partition ID in my Kafka spout?

Comment: I justed looked into the code of `KafkaSpout`. It internally used a variable `_currPartitionIndex` -- I guess you would need to patch `KafkaSpout` to access this information. There is no API to access it.